# Why does SAP login fail with Safari on Lion OS - new Macbook Pro?

Tags: authentication, safari, osx-lion, sap

I am installing my Development environment on my new company issued Macbook Pro with Lion.  When I tried to login to SAP using the Safari browser, it was as-if the javascript could not execute.  I turned on the Error Console and it complained with 404 error for header.js.

Of course, before using the Error Console, I suspected "user error."  The following logins all work:

- Windows7 / Lenovo / IE8.0
- iOS-5 / iPad-1 / Safari
- Macbook / Lion / Chrome

The only one that fails is:

- Macbook / Lion / Safari

I have not found any other reports on the web or with-in SAP or Apple support.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?
Has anyone else found a resolution?

Also note, I did a Software Update on my Macbook and the only update was with iTunes.

Comment: Is the system trying to load a different URL for header.js on OSX/Safari than it is for the others?

Comment: SAP is a company. You did not specify which SAP product you're trying to access or which version you are trying to access - how are we supposed to answer this?

Comment: Funny @vwegert, but I was referring to the company named SAP.  Although I can login from my Windows with IE, I am not able from Mac on Safari.  The problem is long since "not an issue for me" since I am no longer working on an SAP project, but thanks for the kick in the head.

Comment: @mobibob If you are aware that SAP is a company that is selling a gazillion of software products, then why are you talking about "logging on to SAP" without specifying which product you're talking about?

Comment: Are you sure they are selling a gazillion of software products [sic]?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Funny to see that old discussion about SAP company, which is in fact a huge company. SAP is just after Microsoft/Google/IBM, approximately same size as Oracle and SalesForce, and sells hundreds of software...